# Create new list using other list to look up values in dictionary - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider the below situation. I have a list:

```
feature_dict = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

Which just have some strings, all of which are a kind of internal identifiers, completely meaningless. I also have a dictionary (it is filled in different part of code):

```
 phoneDict = dict()
```

This dictionary has mentioned identifiers as keys, and values assigned to them are, well, good values which mean something.

I want to create a new list **preserving the order of original list** (this is crucial) but replacing each element with the value from dictionary. So I thought about creating new list by applying a function to each element of list but with no luck.

I tried to create a fuction:

```
def fastMap(x):
    return phoneDict[x]
```

And then map it:

```
map(fastMap, feature_dict)
```

It just returns me

```
map object at 0x0000000017DFBD30.
```

Nothing else

Anyone tried to solve similar problem?

Comment: `list(map(fastMap, feature_dict))`

Comment: @TimCastelijns lol, that works. Why?

Comment: The `list()` converts the generator returned from map into a real list.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich map returns an iterator in python3.

Comment: Alternate: `[phoneDict[f] for f in feature_list]`

Comment: I would avoid using map with small trivial functions and lambdas if you can. List comprehensions are often more efficient and pythonic, so if what you need can be expressed simply as an expression (pun not intended), a list comprehension like what AShelly has commented is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now it makes sense. Though I think I will use what @AShelly suggested - on big lists it seems to work faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the result to list:

```
list(map(fastMap, feature_dict))
```

Why? `map()` returns an iterator, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map:

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>
> Return an iterator that applies function
>   to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional
>   iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments
>   and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With
>   multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is
>   exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged
>   into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

which you can convert to a list with `list()`

Note: in python 2, `map()` returns a list, but this was changed in python 3 to return an iterator